# 'auth/invalid-api-key' When Letting the Admin SDK discover a service account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, api-key

In different pages of the Firebase Admin SDK documentation, e.g., [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#letting_the_admin_sdk_discover_a_service_account), it is suggested that:

> If your code is deployed in an environment managed by Google, the
>   Admin SDK can attempt to auto-discover... the service account
>   provisioned for your app...To make use of these signing methods,
>   initialize the SDK with Google Application Default credentials and do
>   not specify a service account ID string: `admin.initializeApp();`

When I do this, I get the following error message:

> [Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it
>   correctly.]   code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',   message: 'Your API key
>   is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.'

Note that I do not get this error message when I manually download and import the credentials and service account JSON files in my project.

Detailed information for reproduction of the error:
1- I'm deploying this on Cloud Functions using Firebase CLI. So, basically, I use `firebase deploy`.

2- Here is the minimal code in my Node.js App:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const config = require("./firebase-config");
admin.initializeApp();

const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", Some_Function);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The error happens when I replace `firebase.initializeApp(config);` with `firebase.initializeApp();`

Comment: When using admin  in firebase functions you have to provide valid credentials.
admin.initializeApp(config)

Comment: @ErnestasButa Which documentation page did you find this information on?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup   
Also my bad. You can initialize admin without passing parameters if you have setup environment variable with credential FIREBASE_CONFIG.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters 
explains: "Note: The FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is included automatically in Cloud Functions for Firebase functions that were deployed via the Firebase CLI." Then why should I get that error?

Comment: Maybe they mean that it exists as  "reserved" variable? But you still have to set it. 
Although that's just a speculation. At least for me it doesn't work without parameters

Comment: You've tagged this question google-cloud-functions, so I'm assuming you're running in a Cloud Functions environment. If this is true, please edit the question to show exactly 1) how you are deploying your code, 2) the minimal code itself, 3) which runtime you are targeting.  Please show exact reproduction steps so that anyone can reproduce the error.  We don't know if you're doing something wrong, or if something is misconfigured.

Comment: @DoughStevenson I added the information that you requested to the question. Thank you for considering this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to initialize the Firebase Client SDK in a server-side environment:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

The client SDK accepts a whole different set of credentials compared to `firebase-admin`. You can initialize `firebase-admin` without any arguments in GCP managed environments (e.g. Cloud Functions, Cloud Run), but the same doesn't apply  to `firebase`. You need to provide a valid client app configuration obtained from your Firebase project.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(); // This is ok

const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(); // This is wrong
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object for details on how to obtain a client app configuration.

Also please note that using the client SDK in an environment like Functions is rather unusual. I'd advise you rethink your use case, and see if you really need to use `firebase` client SDK in your function.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. The reason I use `firebase` client SDK in my function is to reduce the overload that `firebase` client SDK adds to the JS bundle that every time someone loads the page should download. Also, for a dynamic website, I was not able to solely rely on the Firestore rules and I needed to check the users' authentication on the server-side to generate appropriate responses based on their previous interactions with the web application.
Is there any more efficient approach for doing this? If yes, I'd appreciate it if you let me know about it.

Comment: At least for the 2nd problem you can look into [ID token verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) or even [session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies). For page load issue, I'd recommend running some actual tests to see if loading the client SDK actually does cause a noticeable delay in page load time. By doing this in server-side you're missing out on lot of clever features that are built into the client SDK.

Comment: I'll go through the links and will do the comparison. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried

- `dotenv` did not work
- `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')` did not work

Step1: go to the console and generate new service account file

Step2: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='path/to/serviceAccount.json'`
(it doesn't matter where it is, e.g : 'user/username/download/serviceAccount.json')

Step3: `if(!admin.apps.length) admin.initializeApp();` [In the docs, either export the json object as param or no param with step 2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)